# Is there an adhesive that I can use to install this PEX tube cover?

Tags: pex, rough-in, cover

The tiles are porcelain
The PEX cover tube is like this one
[image]
Typical installation is like this but I am not sure if the tile is not going to crack

[image]

in my situation the hole around the pipe is not like in their Photoshoped picture :-))
[image]

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible, this guy is hanging a mirror to plain tiles, no holes, just using adhesive
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vFE8aFl52M

And here this lady is doing it with silicone
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9X7cmLhwSJ8&ab_channel=BunningsWarehouse

PS: PL Construction adhesive failed the testing, it did not dry after 36! That was because it cures by drying up and the adhesive was sandwiched between plastic and tiles (finished face) It dried on the exposed to air edges but it was easy to remove. Besides that the exposed edge formed like a seal ring that prevented the rest of it to dry up .... I will use foam to secure the pipe in that hole and then plain silicon to install the esthetic plate you see above.

Answer (score 0):

Since your PEX is straight out and there won't be any force on the flange sideways where you'd need to anchor it to something behind the wall, I'd suggest just using a little bit of bath caulk to hold things in place.  Easy to apply, and can be easily removed if needed.

Comment: Here is the manual for my toilet sit https://www.ovedecors.com/pub/media/amasty/amfile/attach/IM_Stan_Tuva_2020-05-06.pdf I am connecting it using option 1 with PEX piping. As you can see there is a lot of hardware at the end of the pipe and there is a quite rigid 3/4 flexible pipe that is used to connect the toilet. All good reasons for a stiffer cover

Comment: I would give it a try with silicone caulk.  Do you have an appropriate-size porcelain drill bit you can try on a sample piece?

Comment: That could be an idea I fo have some pieces left ...I could try to drill the big hole again and drill small ones after that. I do not have the drill bit yet for screws just the drill bits for pipes, various sizes . I will have to buy it